# MySQL - How to apply LIMIT to GROUP?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, limit

I create a kind of a blog engine, where posts are categorized into *month-year* categories, based on timestamp. I use the following query:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME( post_time ) AS
month , YEAR( post_time ) AS year
FROM blog_posts
GROUP BY year,
month
ORDER BY post_time DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

which returns me the latest ten post categories like this:

```
December 2010
November 2010
...
etc
```

My question is how do I create a query to fetch older/newer categories?

If I had a column like *category_id* I'd be able to easily use it with LIMIT,
but as month and year is all I have I'm stuck.

Help greatly appreciated, this one's a riddle for me.

Comment: *…to fetch older/newer categories…*: older and newer than what? Seems I don't quite understand your question, could you please clarify (best with an example of data and desired output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how do I create a query to fetch older/newer categories?

This query:

```
SELECT  MONTHNAME(post_time) AS month, YEAR(post_time) AS year
FROM    blog_posts
GROUP BY
        year, month
ORDER BY
        post_time DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

groups by months and years and orders by time of the random post within each month and year.

Since the order of these random posts correspond to that of months and years, your categories will go out in correct order (recent to early).

**Update:**

To show `10` categories before `June 2010`:

```
SELECT  MONTHNAME(post_time) AS month, YEAR(post_time) AS year
FROM    blog_posts
WHERE   post_time < '2010-06-01'
GROUP BY
        year, month
ORDER BY
        post_time DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: The core of my question I guess could be can I put both year and month as starting parameters for LIMIT, and fetch the next 10 categories starting from say, June 2010?  Or is there any way to get 10 previous or next month/year combinations (categories) if all I have as an input for a query are current month/year

Comment: I don't have a category column as such, I use GROUP BY to group posts from the same month and year into "virtual" categories. So all I have is month and year, can mysql go ahead and fetch preceding 10 month/year combos for me?

Comment: Thanks, I see the point, but keep getting syntax error for this query

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE post_time < '2010-06-01' ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT 0, 10' at line 5

Comment: @Freelancer: yes, I messed the order of the clauses, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

If blog_posts have category_id

```
SELECT MONTHNAME( post_time ) AS
month , YEAR( post_time ) AS year
FROM blog_posts
GROUP BY year,
month
ORDER BY category_id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Comment: blog posts have their own id's, but I don't have a category_id, that is in fact my issue