# MYSQL Group by column with 2 rows for each group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I need 2 `id` for each group.

```
SELECT `id`, `category`.`cat_name` 
FROM `info`
LEFT JOIN `category` ON `info`.`cat_id` = `category`.`cat_id`
WHERE `category`.`cat_name` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `category`.`cat_name`
ORDER BY `category`.`cat_name` ASC
```

How to do this?

Sample Data:

```
id  cat_name
1   Cat-1
2   Cat-1
3   Cat-2
4   Cat-1
5   Cat-2
6   Cat-1
7   Cat-2
```

Output Will be:

```
id  cat_name
6   Cat-1
4   Cat-1
7   Cat-2
5   Cat-2
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired result.

Comment: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(info.id), GROUP_CONCAT(category.id),...`

Comment: Which "2 rows" do you want?  Any two rows?  The two rows that have the highest ids, which seems to be what your output shows?

Comment: I need latest 2 rows for each group @RickJames

Comment: Did you check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15295544/4236400) on a related question?

Answer (score 5):

If you need two arbitrary ids, then use `min()` and `max()`:

```
SELECT c.`cat_name` , min(id), max(id)
FROM `info` i INNER JOIN
     `category` c
     ON i.`cat_id` = c.`cat_id`
WHERE c.`cat_name` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY c`.`cat_name`
ORDER BY c.`cat_name` ASC ;
```

Note:  You are using a `LEFT JOIN` and then aggregating by a column in the *second* table.  This is usually not a good idea, because non-matches are all placed in a `NULL` group.  Furthermore, your `WHERE` clause turns the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` anyway, so I've fixed that.  The `WHERE` clause may or may not be necessary, depending on whether or not `cat_name` is ever `NULL`.

If you want the two biggest or smallest -- and can bear to have them in the same column:

```
SELECT c.`cat_name`,
       substring_index(group_concat id order by id), ',', 2) as ids_2 
FROM `info` i INNER JOIN
     `category` c
     ON i.`cat_id` = c.`cat_id`
WHERE c.`cat_name` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY c`.`cat_name`
ORDER BY c.`cat_name` ASC ;
```

Comment: Thaks for share your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  id, cat_name
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  @prev := '', @n := 0 ) init
    JOIN  
      ( SELECT  @n := if(c.cat_name != @prev, 1, @n + 1) AS n,
                @prev := c.cat_name,
                c.cat_name,
                i.id
            FROM  `info`
            LEFT JOIN  `category` ON i.`cat_id` = c.`cat_id`
            ORDER BY  c.cat_name ASC, i.id DESC 
      ) x
    WHERE  n <= 2
    ORDER BY  cat_name ASC, id DESC;
```

[*More discussion in Group-wise-max blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max).

Answer (score 0):

In a database that supported window functions, you could enumerate the position of each record in each group (*ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cat_name ORDER BY id DESC)*) and then select those records in relative position 1 or 2.

In MySQL, you can mimic this by a self-join which counts the number of records whose `id` is greater-than-or-equal-to a record of the same `cat_name` (*PARTITION ... ORDER BY id DESC*).  Record #1 in a `cat_name` group has only one record of >= its `id`, and record #*N* has *N* such records.

This query

```
 SELECT id, cat_name
   FROM (   SELECT c.id, c.cat_name, COUNT(1) AS relative_position_in_group
              FROM category c
         LEFT JOIN category others
                ON c.cat_name = others.cat_name
                   AND
                   c.id <= others.id
          GROUP BY 1, 2) d
   WHERE relative_position_in_group <= 2
ORDER BY cat_name, id DESC;
```

produces:

```
+----+----------+
| id | cat_name |
+----+----------+
|  6 | Cat-1    |
|  4 | Cat-1    |
|  7 | Cat-2    |
|  5 | Cat-2    |
+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is like `Select id, cat_name from mytable group by cat_name` then update it to `Select SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(id), ',', 2), cat_name from mytable group by cat_name` and you will get output like as follows

```
id  cat_name
1,2   Cat-1
3,5   Cat-2
```

Does it helps?

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you need is adding `limit option` to the end of your query and `ordering in descending` order as shown below:

```
SELECT `id`, `category`.`cat_name` 
FROM `info`
LEFT JOIN `category` ON `info`.`cat_id` = `category`.`cat_id`
WHERE `category`.`cat_name` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `category`.`cat_name`
ORDER BY `category`.`cat_name` DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: I don't think it would work. This will limit the final results to 2, not on a per group basis.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple Group By ID. it is group duplicate data

Answer (score 0):

I have written query for you. I hope it will resolve your problem :

```
SELECT 
    id, cat_name
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *,
            @prevcat,
            CASE
                WHEN cat_name != @prevcat THEN @rownum:=0
            END,
            @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS cnt,
            @prevcat:=cat_name
    FROM
        category
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0, @prevcat:='') r
    ORDER BY cat_name ASC , id DESC) AS t
WHERE
    t.cnt <= 2;
```

Comment: @Chayan, select it as a answer if you find it suitable to your problem solution

Answer (score 0):

Better to use rank function the below sample query for your ouput will be helpful check it

```
select a.* from 
(
select a, b ,rank() over(partition by b order by a desc) as rank
from a
group by b,a) a

where rank<=2
```

Comment: MySQL does not have ``Rank`` function

Answer (score 0):

please try this, it worked in the  sample data given

```
SELECT `id`, `category`.`cat_name`
FROM `info`
LEFT JOIN `category` ON `info`.`cat_id` = `category`.`cat_id`
WHERE `category`.`cat_name` IS NOT NULL and (SELECT count(*) 
FROM info t
WHERE t.id>=info.id and t.cat_id=category.cat_id )<3

GROUP BY `category`.`cat_name`,id
ORDER BY `category`.`cat_name` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's pretty ugly, but it looks like it works.

```
select
cat_name,
max(id) as maxid
from
table1
group by cat_name
union all
select
cat_name,
max(id) as maxid
from
table1
where not exists
(select 
  cat_name,
  maxid
  from 
  (select cat_name,max(id) as maxid from table1  group by cat_name) t
  where t.cat_name = table1.cat_name and t.maxid = table1.id)
group by cat_name
order by cat_name
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/acd1b/2)

Basically, it takes the max for each cat_name, and then unions that to  a second query that excludes the actual max id for each cat_name, allowing you to get the second largest id for each.  Hopefully all that made sense...

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, cat_name from 

(
 select @rank:=if(@prev_cat=cat_name,@rank+1,1) as rank,
         id,cat_name,@prev_cat:=cat_name
from Table1,(select @rank:=0, @prev_cat:="")t
   order by cat_name, id desc
) temp

where temp.rank<=2
```

You may verify result at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/acd1b/7