# How to select from a table multiple results which has same category in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can I get random and limited and multiple results from a mysql table?

Table name:

```
questions
```

It has several columns:

```
 id | question | choice | second_choice | category
 1  | some txt |   a    |       b       |   sport
 2  | some txt |   c    |       e       |   sport
 3  | some txt |   c    |       e       |   sport
 4  | some txt |   a    |       b       |   job
 5  | some txt |   y    |       w       |   job
 6  | some txt |   y    |       w       |   job
 7  | some txt |   l    |       c       |   hobby
 8  | some txt |   p    |       o       |   hobby
 9  | some txt |   p    |       o       |   hobby
```

And I want to get 2 questions from every category and of course randomly.
So I will have all in all 6 questions, and 2-2-2 from every category

Is it possible to do  it in codeigniter?
If yes please help me. Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093420/mysql-group-by-column-with-2-rows-for-each-group) may help guide you in the correct direction

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to change 2 to 5 so I get 5 from each?